# My code failed to iterate on somesection of the code

Tags: python, iteration

I have this python function code that suppose to balance up the number of "bracket" in any parameter supply.
Though, it work well with require problem in the exercise but when the parameter contain 4 or more bracket the function failed to balance it up. below is the code.

```
def closedBracket(string_input):
   import  unicodedata, re
   left_bracket = re.compile('[\u0028]')
   right_bracket = re.compile('[\u0029]')
   left_bracket = len(left_bracket.findall(string_input))
   right_bracket = len(right_bracket.findall(string_input))
   if left_bracket > right_bracket:
      # Remove  the leftmost bracket or add one last right bracket
      count = 0
      largest_bracket = (left_bracket - right_bracket)
      while count <= largest_bracket:
         final_string = str(string_input) + '\u0029'
         count += 1
      print('False', final_string)
   elif left_bracket < right_bracket:
      # Remove the last Rightmost Bracket or add another leftmost bracket
      count = 0
      largest_bracket = (right_bracket - left_bracket)
      while count <= largest_bracket:
         final_string = '\u0028' + str(string_input)
         count += 1
      print('False', final_string)

   else:
     print('True')

closedBracket("(5+3)*2)")

The output is "False ((5+3)*2)"
```

The above function work on the supply parameter, but when I run it on the below supply parameter, the output is wrong, so I need advise on what to do.

```
def closedBracket(string_input):
   import  unicodedata, re
   left_bracket = re.compile('[\u0028]')
   right_bracket = re.compile('[\u0029]')
   left_bracket = len(left_bracket.findall(string_input))
   right_bracket = len(right_bracket.findall(string_input))
   if left_bracket > right_bracket:
      # Remove  the leftmost bracket or add one last right bracket
      count = 0
      largest_bracket = (left_bracket - right_bracket)
      while count <= largest_bracket:
         final_string = str(string_input) + '\u0029'
         count += 1
      print('False', final_string)
   elif left_bracket < right_bracket:
      # Remove the last Rightmost Bracket or add another leftmost bracket
      count = 0
      largest_bracket = (right_bracket - left_bracket)
      while count <= largest_bracket:
         final_string = '\u0028' + str(string_input)
         count += 1
      print('False', final_string)

   else:
     print('True')

closedBracket("((((5+3)*2)")

The output is "False ((((5+3)*2))" and this is wrong
```

Comment: This is not how you validate parenthesization, use a stack.

Comment: The exercise demand that i should not use any of python module or package. It should be non exist function

Comment: @Bode: a stack is a list, with two methods. `append` and `pop`. Plus `len`.

Answer (score 0):

In the cycle you have this line

```
final_string = str(string_input) + '\u0029'
```

Which means that each time you take *input string* and add `)` to it. So no matter how many iterations you do `final_string` will always be equal to `input_string` joined with `)`.

Comment: thanks. what I want to do is to add '( or )' to the 'str(string_input)' inasmuch my counter is not exceeded. So, from the code can you guide me to what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who come to my rescue, particularly @Alik,
The solution to the above python code is solved under the "while loop" section.
1.  This function is name closedBracket(), it take mathematical expression, iterate over the expression to determine the number of both open and closing parenthesis, if there is unbalance number of parenthesis, the function will
return a balance version of the mathematical expression
2.  The function take on parameter

The rework complete code is given below:

```
def closedBracket(string_input):
    import  unicodedata, re
    left_bracket = re.compile('[\u0028]')   # compiling unicode of left
    right_bracket = re.compile('[\u0029]')  # compiling unicode of right
    string_holder = []      # Declaring empty List to hold split string
    string_holder[:0] = string_input # Change the input string to list
    left_bracket = string_holder.count('\u0028')
    right_bracket = string_holder.count('\u0029')
    final_string = []   # Accumulator of
    if left_bracket > right_bracket:
        # Remove  some  leftmost brackets or add more right brackets
        count = 0
        while count < (left_bracket - right_bracket):
            final_string.append('\u0029',) 
            count += 1
        final_string = ''.join(final_string)

        print('False', string_input + final_string)

    elif left_bracket < right_bracket:
        #Remove the last Rightmost Brackets or add another leftmost )
        count = 0
        number_right_bracket = (right_bracket - left_bracket)
        while count < number_right_bracket:
            final_string.append('\u0028',)
            count += 1
        final_string = ''.join(final_string)
        print('False', final_string + string_input)

    else:
        return True

closedBracket("5+((3)*2)))))")
```